# How do I calculate the expected value of a binomial distribution for a genetics example?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution, expected-value, binary-data, genetics

I have model with 20 genes which can take on a value of 1 or 0 (the alleles). What is their expected value and variance assuming the alleles are selected with equal probability?

Is this just a binomial distribution?

Comment: You need to know whether those genes take on the values *independently.*  Is that the case or not?

Comment: Yes, their values are assigned independently

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming independence and equal probabilities, this is just the binomial distribution. So the number of alleles of value 1 is $X\sim \mathcal{Binom}(20,p)$.